# Kubernetes postStart seems to wreck shop for everything in deployment

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine, supervisord

We have the following deployment `yaml`:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{DEP_ENVIRONMENT}}-{{SERVICE_NAME}}
  namespace: {{DEP_ENVIRONMENT}}
  labels:
    app: {{DEP_ENVIRONMENT}}-{{SERVICE_NAME}}
spec:
  replicas: {{NUM_REPLICAS}}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{DEP_ENVIRONMENT}}-{{SERVICE_NAME}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{DEP_ENVIRONMENT}}-{{SERVICE_NAME}}
    spec:
      # [START volumes]
      volumes:
        - name: {{CLOUD_DB_INSTANCE_CREDENTIALS}}
          secret:
            secretName: {{CLOUD_DB_INSTANCE_CREDENTIALS}}
      # [END volumes]
      containers:
      # [START proxy_container]
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                  "-instances=<PROJECT_ID>:{{CLOUD_DB_CONN_INSTANCE}}=tcp:3306",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        # [START cloudsql_security_context]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        # [END cloudsql_security_context]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: {{CLOUD_DB_INSTANCE_CREDENTIALS}}
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
      # [END proxy_container]
      - name: {{DEP_ENVIRONMENT}}-{{SERVICE_NAME}}
        image: {{IMAGE_NAME}}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: CLOUD_DB_HOST
          value: 127.0.0.1
        - name: DEV_CLOUD_DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: {{CLOUD_DB_DB_CREDENTIALS}}
              key: username
        - name: DEV_CLOUD_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: {{CLOUD_DB_DB_CREDENTIALS}}
              key: password
      # [END cloudsql_secrets]
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "supervisord"]
```

The last `lifecycle` block is new and is causing the database connection to be refused.  This config works fine without the `lifecycle` block.  I'm sure that there is something stupid here that I am missing but for the life of my cannot figure out what it is.

Note:  we are only trying to start Supervisor like this as a workaround for huge issues when attempting to start it normally.

Comment: Hi, the hook handler need to be in completed  phase after then database connection would be executed.  is supervisord continuously running ?

Comment: You can check the state of the handler, in the status phase of the container 'kubectl get pods $POD -o yaml`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Supervisord is meant to be started by this handler and then left to run continuously from that point on.  I'm guessing that if the handler executes a command that is left to run then that doesn't qualify as "complete" for the lifecycle handler?

Comment: > The postStart handler runs asynchronously relative to the Container’s code, but Kubernetes’ management of the container blocks until the postStart handler completes. The Container’s status is not set to RUNNING until the postStart handler completes,https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers

Comment: yea, I think it needs to be in completed phase, nevertheless, whats the point of supervisord ?

Comment: what kind of events are we getting `kubectl describe pod $POD`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lifecycle hooks are intended to be short foreground commands. You cannot start a background daemon from them, that has to be the main `command` for the container.